Trying to find a simple way of getting the radio buttons input from this vanilla JS code
I am trying to create an option for the user to select their gender using these ionic radio buttons. However I'm not sure what the simplest solution would be.
HTML
 <ion-item>
                      <ion-radio-group id="genderradioGroup" value="male">
                          <ion-list-header>
                              What Is Your Gender?
                          </ion-list-header>
                      
                          <ion-radio value="male">Male</ion-radio><br />
                          <ion-radio value="female">Female</ion-radio><br />
                          <ion-radio value="pref-not-to-say">Prefer Not To Say</ion-radio><br />
                      </ion-radio-group>
                  </ion-item>

I tried asking ChatGPT in the hopes that would be to help me, but I can't get any messages in the logs that indicated that the selection is working.
ChatGPT JS

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const genderradioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#genderradioGroup ion-radio');
      
        // Loop through each radio button and add event listener
        genderradioButtons.forEach(function(radioButton) {
            radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                const genderselectedValue = radioButton.getAttribute('value');
                console.log("Gender:", genderselectedValue);
                // You can perform any action with the selected value here
            });
        });
    });


What steps have you taken to debug this? It seems to work fine for me when I click on each item.

Here is your code in a code snippet. As you can see eveything work correctly when i click on a div its logged in the console.
Maybe check that there is no some css rules that prevent the click to be caught.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const genderradioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#genderradioGroup ion-radio');

    // Loop through each radio button and add event listener
    genderradioButtons.forEach(function(radioButton) {
        radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const genderselectedValue = radioButton.getAttribute('value');
            console.log("Gender:", genderselectedValue);
            // You can perform any action with the selected value here
        });
    });
});
<ion-item>
    <ion-radio-group id="genderradioGroup" value="male">
        <ion-list-header>
            What Is Your Gender?
        </ion-list-header>

        <ion-radio value="male">Male</ion-radio><br />
        <ion-radio value="female">Female</ion-radio><br />
        <ion-radio value="pref-not-to-say">Prefer Not To Say</ion-radio><br />
    </ion-radio-group>
</ion-item>



